ABP.io blazor server project datagrid auto update without refreshing the UI
I'm working on ABP.oi framework blazor server project.
Now I need to make grids auto update.
For an example, let's assume it will be created new author by an user using this sample and some other user is always opening the author's data grid and when it is added new author, then it needs to automatically update the data grid without refreshing the UI. But ABP.io documentation doesn't mention any special implementation for doing it.
Any expert can give me a clue for doing it?
[I did not add any code in here, because this question will be so lengthy. Otherwise I'm a beginner to ABP blazor server and simply pick above link's ABP code up to my project.]
